# how to extract AM/PM part from datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to extract  AM/PM part from datetime in sql

Comment: A `datetime` doesn't have an AM/PM part. A textual "AM/PM" indicator may be added if it is converted into a string, but this isn't how it is stored in the database.

Comment: yes i want AM/PM from that converted DAte

Comment: Then [show us your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you'll need to focus on the *front-end* program that is getting the data from the database, not the database itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the hour value:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, <DATETIME>) > 11 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'AM' END
```

Comment: @user665642 If you found the answer useful, click on the checkmark button next to the question to mark it as the answer.